# Docker getting started part 3 "Connection refused" when using "docker stack deploy", "docker-compose up" works

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

I'm trying to complete the tutorial at https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part3.

I've followed the instructions carefully but when I try to connect to `http://localhost:4000` I get the following error:

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 4000: Connection refused

I'm using the following command to start the services as instructed: `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml getstartedlab`

Running `docker container ls -q` shows that I have 5 tasks running.

If I run the same image with `docker run -p 4000:80 mvescovo/get-started:part2` then it works.

If I use `docker-compose up` then it also works. However to be able to test the "load balancing" feature I need to use the stack deploy command (from above).

This is my docker-compose file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    # replace username/repo:tag with your name and image details
    image: mvescovo/get-started:part2
    deploy:
      replicas: 5
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.1"
          memory: 50M
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    ports:
      - "4000:80"
    networks:
      - webnet
networks:
  webnet:
```

What might be causing this? I'm on standard Ubuntu 18.04.1 install.

I've tried it on 2 separate machines and get the same problem each time.

**You should be able to reproduce the error - if not that would be interesting.** I'm using "docker-compose version 1.22.0, build f46880fe".

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: What version of docker are you using?

Comment: ok so I tried it on my home machine (3rd machine) and it worked! I'll have to check the work machine tomorrow but home machine is "Docker version 18.06.0-ce, build 0ffa825". It has the same docker-compose version.

Comment: I think an earlier version of docker required a separate scaling service.

Comment: ok so one of the work machines is the same version (18.06.0-ce, build 0ffa825) and one is a slightly older version (17.06.2-ce, build a04f55b). So at least for the one that's the same version I'm at a loss as to why it doesn't work when I've followed the exact same instructions.

Comment: I'm going to reinstall the OS and try again.

Comment: ok I found the discrepancy and posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I got it to work on both work machines.

All up I tried it on 3 machines (2 at work and 1 at home). The home machine worked while the 2 work machines didn't.

I checked docker versions on all of them. The home machine and one of the work machines had "18.06.0-ce, build 0ffa825", while the other work machine had "17.06.2-ce, build a04f55b".

On the machine with the oldest version I tried to uninstall docker but was unsuccessful. It just wouldn't go away when following the instructions here: https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu

This got me thinking and then I discovered it was installed as a snap. **Uninstalling the snap and then installing docker via the instructions at the above link resolved the issue**.

I'm not sure if it was the version (haven't tried manually installing that version) or something about using the snap, but using docker as a snap is no longer supported as mentioned here: https://github.com/docker/docker-snap.

Comment: Glad you got through this.  Hopefully it will help someone else